# How to get rid of Warning message from customized Raiserror - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, raiserror

I want to display a popup on the screen when an update query is not fired.
I am using Raiserror to raise and error and display a customised error message which is displayed in the popup.

```
if(some condition)
begin

update  Tab1vendorInside
set 
VendorBatchCode=a.VendorBatchCode,
Quantity=a.Quantity,--case  When (PlannedDispatchQty>=a.Quantity) then a.Quantity  Else 0 end,
OfferedForInspectionOn=convert(varchar(80),convert(date, getdate())),
[Time]=convert(varchar(8), convert(time, getdate())) ,
CTDTDSReference=a.CTDTDSReference,
Certificateupload=a.Certificateupload,
Active=a.Active
from @TP a
inner join Tab1vendorInside 
on a.ID=Tab1vendorInside.ID and
a.Material=Tab1vendorInside.Material
and Datepart(mm,a.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)=Datepart(mm,Tab1vendorInside.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)
and Datepart(year,a.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)=Datepart(year,Tab1vendorInside.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)
inner join Tab1Vendor
on Tab1Vendor.Material=a.Material and Tab1Vendor.ID=a.TaboneVendorID
and Datepart(mm,a.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)=Datepart(mm,Tab1Vendor.PlannedDateofDispatch)
and Datepart(year,a.PlannedDispatchQtyDate)=Datepart(year,Tab1Vendor.PlannedDateofDispatch)
end

else
begin
--if it enters else, logically it means that the data is updated.
begin try
select 16/0
end try
begin catch
RAISERROR('Quantity limit exceeded! Data insert/update failed.',16,1);  
end catch
end
```

Well its working fine, but the problem is, I am getting additional message attached to the my customised msg.

> Quantity limit exceeded! Data insert/update failed. Warning: Null
>   value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I want to get rid of the *Warning Null value is eliminated*... etc etc
how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

This will suppress the warning you are seeing. However it looks like it could also be fixed by adding a NULL check somewhere in your query. I can't say where as full details are your code haven't been posted.

If you do choose the quick fix of suppressing the warning just make sure you enable it again afterwards in your code by doing the following:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Comment: Actually I already tried that. didnt help. Can you explain me about the null value. I have edited my code. Its actually update query and not insert

Comment: Now I can see your code, the raise error is happening in a block of code that is being run because the condition on line 1 is false, therefore it's not anything to do with your update statement.

Comment: See a good explanation of the warning courtesy of sqlauthority: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/13/sql-server-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/